# Properties (bpy.props) don't update with keyframes and drivers?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes, properties

My properties don't update (with the update function) when animating them using drivers or keyframe.
the value do change in the interface but no update signal is sent!
What am i suppose to do?
Did i missed something?
Is this a known python limitation ?

please don't tell me i need to use a handler to refresh every settings.. :-(

[image]

Comment: Hmm i believe i need to use set=update_fct. instead of the update=update_fct ?
it seem that set react to drivers

Comment: Remember being disappointed this didn't work with 2.5 back in circa 2007.

Comment: created a task for this issue https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-to-make-our-bpy-props-python-properties-update-with-drivers-keyframes/18023/2

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been brought up to the developers in a bug report https://developer.blender.org/T63793

It is a known limitation.

The reply from Dr Stüvel from the developers team :

> The issue is that an object is not "tagged for update" in the
> dependency graph when a custom property is changed by Python. "Tagged
> for update" means that Blender understands that the object (and
> everything that depends on it) should be updated. This is done for a
> few reasons:
>
> Tagging the object for update requires a reference to that object.
> This is available for simple cases like `some_ob["prop"]`, but not for
> nested cases like `some_ob["complex_prop"][3]["something"]`. Updating
> an object could mean recalculating its constraints and modifiers,
> which can be expensive. This may not even be necessary for that
> particular custom property, but when exactly this is or is not
> necessary can be hard to determine. As a result, this could make
> Blender slower than necessary.
>
> After setting the custom property, call `C.object.update_tag()`. This
> should take care of the updates not "being seen" by dependencies. It
> won't trigger a full redraw of Blender's UI, though, so until that
> happens things on screen may still show the old status.

So it might work on `bpy.types.Object` blender objects, but I don't see how to use it in property groups or in objects which have a number of dependencies.

I found that like you pointed in the comments, the `set` callback of the custom property is rightfully triggered, but not the `update` one. This is however a bit limiting since the `set` callback doesn't carry over the current `context` which may be necessary to have in the following update logic.

Comment: thanks for the info

Note that they don't talk about the same kind of properties

Comment: @DB3D How are they different from the custom properties in your question ?