How can I add a library override to a non-API custom property from a linked file with Python?
The question regards setting custom properties of a linked file via Python.
Because when setting the property like
bpy.data.objects["myControl"]["speed"] = 1.0
the value changes but isn't reflected in the scene.
When trying to update the scene via
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
there is no visible change.
I notice that when setting the value with Python the field doesn't change color like when setting the property manually. However, when saving the file and reopening, the value indeed gets applied and the field is colored because of the library override. But I'd rather not save the file and reopen after every parameter change.
How can setting the property done with Python the right way, so that it properly registers as a library override?
Note, that this question is not about having missed to set the property as overridable or that no overrides have been established yet. All of this is perfectly clear, as the property can be set manually. The question is about setting the property value through the use of Python.
Thanks for any hints on the matter.

I think you wanna look into setting an update callback on your FloatProperty.

The property isn't part of an add-on but a property on a rig. The Python script is for setting various states. Think of it as running it as sort of a preset.

Hello. I took the liberty to add a bit more context to your question title, as it seems to have caused a bit of confusion. Feel free to revert if you don't like it

That's fine. Thanks.

Change the value of non-api-defined library overridable custom property via Python
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object
ob["prop"] = 0.5

ob.location[0] = ob.location[0] # refresh the UI

Or
# But the UI is not updated immediately
ob.update_tag()
bpy.context.view_layer.update()


Thanks. But this isn't it because this is why I added "Note, that this question is not about having missed to set the property as overridable or that no overrides have been established yet."
All these steps have been taken. The value is not greyed out to begin with. But setting the property manually it has a visual effect in the scene and the field color turns turquiose. This does not happen when setting the value with Python.

You may provide a simple setup script and we can reproduce the problem.

The property has been added manually through the Blender UI. No scripting involved. It's not about setting up the property.

Create a scene with an object and a custom property. Set the property to "library overridable".
Link this object in to another scene file.
Create the library override as usual so that the property is accessible.
When setting the value manually the field color turns turquoise.
But when you set the property with Python like bpy.data.objects["myControl"]["speed"] = 1.0 the field color doesn't change.


Thanks for the info. Check out the new one, it worked for me in blender 4.1, after running the script it turned turquoise.

Yes thanks, that's what I just figured as well. .update_tag() does the trick even though the change isn't immediately visible in the scene. But as soon as the view gets navigated the change is there. That's fine. bpy.context.view_layer.update() has no effect in this case.
A more extensive explanation can be found here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/215281/146135
